# External display brightness dim - Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: multiple-monitors, 22.04, display, brightness

### System configuration:

- Dell XPS 13 9310 2-in-1 laptop
- Intel i7 11th Gen
- Mesa Intel XE Graphics (TGL GT2)
- Ubuntu 22.04 LTS 64 bit
- Gnome version 42.5
- Wayland windowing system

### External displays used:

- Dell S2817Q (4k)
- HP 2509M

### HDMI to USB-C Adapter used:

- Mokin MUC0501B

I used HP 2509M for around 3-4 months and suddenly one day, the external display brightness just dimmed. I had not changed any brightness settings at all, neither on the laptop nor on the external display itself. Then I switched to the Dell display and after roughly the same amount of time, I am facing the same issue with this display. Issue persists irrespective of extended display mode - single, mirror or extend.

### Triaging

- Tried upgrading the display drivers, and also tried the xrandr command, but to no effect.

| xrandr -q |grep " connected"

XWAYLAND12 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 620mm x 340mm

| xrandr --output XWAYLAND12 --brightness 0.9

- Tried changing the USB-C to HDMI adapter to isolate if the issue is in the adapter, issue persists even with a different adapter.
- Tried connecting external display to a Windows machine, external display brightness is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by changing the color profile of the external display under Settings > Color